# Javascript switch and if statements with multiple conditions doing something really strange?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm trying to make a function that changes the value of the attribute x or y of the dot object four times, each time only if two conditions are met. The variable permissionSomething has to be 1, and x or y has to be more or less then a certain number, because in this case it is used for a moving dot on a canvas, which has to stay within the canvas. PermissionSomething is set to 1 if a certain key is pressed down, and changes back to the default value of -1 if that key goes up again.

```
var permissionLeft = -1;
var permissionRight = -1;
var permissionUp = -1;
var permissionDown = -1;

function update()
{
    switch (true)
    {
        case permissionLeft = 1 && dot.x > 29: 
        dot.x--;
        break;
        case permissionRight = 1 && dot.x < 841: 
        dot.x++;
        break;
        case permissionUp = 1 && dot.y > 29: 
        dot.y--;
        break;
        case permissionDown = 1 && dot.y < 541:
        dot.y++;
        break;
    }
}
```

If I run this, even without pressing any key, it starts to move in some strange way, stops and starts moving back and forth. If I don't press any keys permissionSomething should never be 1 so it should never move. The same thing happens if I write four if-statements like this:

```
if (permissionLeft = 1 && dot.x > 29) {
dot.x--};

if (.....
```

Comment: You probably want to use `==` comparison instead of `=` assignment...

Comment: Very strange to use switch-case like that.